# Why no women beards?

Tags: women, beard

Since the [Zohar (1:205b)](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/88833/jewish/Chapter-12-A-Lightning-Rod-To-The-Spiritual-Realms.htm#footnoteRef3a88833) explains everything in the physical world mirrors everything in the spiritual world, what is the Torah reason why the Creator didn't have women grow beards too? (I can't imagine it would seem strange for men if that's the way women always looked)

Comment: Is there a reason why this question should be closed? I've seen Rabbonim address this question in the past...just today I saw https://www.torchweb.org/torah_detail.php?id=367 - but wanted to see other ideas...

Comment: The question should be closed because it is not about Judaism.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Is "the Torah reason why the Creator [X]" not a detail of Judaism?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok The scope of Judaism includes the directives Hashem imposed on our Briah. It would follow that the inquiry of Hashem’s intent (Torah reason) concerning the lack of a particular feature (beards on women) is included within that scope.

Comment: What does the fact that everything mirrors the spiritual world have to do with women having beards? The women angels have beards?

Comment: @Dani Seemingly "female" angels (do they exist?) don't have beards since females in this world generally don't. My quoting the Zohar was to emphasize the fact that a question about the physical world is indeed a question related to Judaism.

Comment: I agree with Dani here. I don't understand the motivation for the question. You could just as well have asked, "What is the Torah reason why penguins can't fly?" or "What is the Torah reason why bananas are yellow?" The [how to ask](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page explains that you should "[m]ake it clear how your question is relevant to more people than just you." Explaining the motivation for your question helps us understand why we should care and that this question isn't just idle musings.

Comment: @Daniel Hmmm, I hear your point. I'm trying to hear some explanation from a Torah perspective as to why Hashem decided to make something in the world. Yes, I might (don't worry, I won't) ask why Hashem made penguins birds but not fly or why He made bananas yellow (Rav Avigdor talks about the general beauty and exotic array of colors of fruits while they are green to remain hidden in the leaves while not yet ripe). In this case, I want to know a Torah understanding why women don't have beards

Comment: I vote that this be closed as unclear instead of the current close reason. Why should "everything in the physical world mirrors the spiritual world" imply "women should have beards"? cc @DoubleAA

Comment: Everything in the physical world mirrors the spiritual world is trying to explain why there must be a good spiritual reason why women don't have a beard.

Comment: Women with PCOS grow beards

Comment: I've seen many women w beards

Comment: @FalseMessiah I would be imagine that is much more the exception than the rule. Although it is true some women may have visible facial hair, it doesn't seem to have much recognition in halacha. For instance, women are generally allowed to shave facial hair during the three weeks https://ohr.edu/1146 as opposed to specific reasons for men

Comment: That's right njm